# IIS site not visible on alias creation step while installing Webcon

Tags: iis, sharepoint, webcon

Webcon cannot see any IIS site provided by SharePoint on creating alias step, but I was able to select proper SharePoint web-application and it installed all Webcon solutions successful.

It should create an alias under SharePoint site, just like that: `https://portal.sharepoint.com/WEBCONBPS`, but to be able to do this the SharePoint site (in IIS) should be visible. Installation account, IIS web-pool account and even farm account: they all have `db_owner` role on SQL Server instance for each database, `farm administrator` and `site-collection administrator` permission in the SharePoint farm and they all are `local administrators` across the all farm servers (for testing purposes).

There are four servers in this farm (first-second frontend role, third-fourth application role).

I guess it's not a SharePoint related problem, but still can't figure it out.

[image]